# How do I specify a unicode literal that requires more than four hex digits in Antlr?

Tags: unicode, antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis, unicode-literals

I want to define a lexer rule for ranges between unicode characters that have code points that need more than four hexadecimal digits to identify. To be concrete, I want to declare the following rule:

```
ID_Continue : [\uE0100-\uE01EF] ;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This rule will match characters that are not in this range. (I'm not certain to what exact behaviour this results in, but it isn't the one I want.) I've tried also the following (padding with leading zeros and using 8 digits):

```
ID_Continue : [\U000E0100-\U000E01EF] ;
```

But it seems to result in the same unwanted behaviour.

I am using Antlr4 and the IntelliJ plugin for it for testing.

Does Antlr4 not support unicode literals above `\uFFFF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ANTLR's max is the same as Java's [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE)

If you look at (a part of) [ANTLR4's lexer grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/LexBasic.g4) you will see these rules:

```
// Any kind of escaped character that we can embed within ANTLR literal strings.
fragment EscSeq
    :   Esc
        ( [btnfr"'\\]   // The standard escaped character set such as tab, newline, etc.
        | UnicodeEsc    // A Unicode escape sequence
        | .             // Invalid escape character
        | EOF           // Incomplete at EOF
        )
    ;

...

fragment UnicodeEsc
    :   'u' (HexDigit (HexDigit (HexDigit HexDigit?)?)?)?
    ;

...

fragment Esc : '\\' ;
```

Comment: I did look there, but I wanted to be absolutely sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note: the limitation to the BMP is purely a Java limitation. Other targets might go much further. For instance [my MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/grammar/MySQL.g), written for ANTLR3 (C target) can easily lex e.g. emojis from beyond the BMP. This works for quoted strings as well as IDENTIFIERs.

[image]

What's a bit strange here is however that I haven't specified that range in the grammar (it uses only the BMP). Still the parser can parse any utf-8 input. Might be a bug in the target runtime, though I'm happy it exists :-D